# Is there a way to fix my Windows Server if winload.exe is deleted/corrupted without a usb?

Tags: windows-10, boot, windows-server-2019

I am a student starting a Sys Admin class and my teacher gave us a challenge to try to repair a Windows Server 2019 VM and I can't use snapshots or anything like that I have to legit patch it and show how I did and I can use outside resources.

So the winload.exe file was deleted/corrupted and we have to try and fix it without a USB but if we abosolutely can't we are allowed to use one. What happens after a reset is it takes you to a blue screen and fails to boot (because of winload yes) and the auto repair tool cannot fix it so that leaves me from what ive been reading potentially using a USB to try to get it to work OR using command prompt. For CMD here is what ive tried:

`Bootrec /fixmbr`
`Bootrec /fixboot` (this one says access denied when I do it! How could I get around that if this is my fix?)
`Bootrec /rebuildbcd`

With that I could be missreading and the forums I'm reading still tell me I need a usb/cd with that step still but idk. If anyone knows anything else that's why I'm here and your help would be greatly appreciated!

Bonus Question: I also read this step on another post and was wondering if the Windows10 tool actually works with Win Server 2019 (it should I believe but just making sure idk you guys are the geniuses here)

```
Download Windows 10 Media Creation tool in a USB or CD.
```

Comment: Why are you using a Windows 10 ISO to repair a Windows Server 3019 install?

Comment: @Ramhound 2019* and the post was about someone with the same problem but on windows 10. is there a tool thats separate for windows 2019 server? If not wouldnt this be my only option but to just use my 2019 iso with the win10 tool?

Edit: Answered my own question I can use the win10 creation tool :)

Comment: The Windows 10 Media Creation Tool can only be used download a Windows 10 ISO. Windows Server 2019 cannot be downloaded with that tool. The media creation tool of course, itself cannot be used to fix, any windows problem.